# Graph's data in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiview, graph

I've been developing apps in swift, for a few months, and I can't figure out how to pass data to a chart. So basically what I have is a view controller with an array inside, and a UIView, that contains the chart. What I want to do is that the graph in the UIView paints the array in the ViewController. So what I want is that the data from the array dataMoneyTracker1 in the view controller is passed to the array graphPoints in the UIView, or that I can access from the uiview to the array in the view controller.

Thanks for your answers!

Here's my code:

VIEW CONTROLLER

```
import UIKit

class GonDetail2ViewController: UIViewController {
var dataMoneyTracker1 = [Int]()
@IBOutlet var View1: UIView!

}
```

UIVIEW

```
import UIKit

class GonGraphUIView: UIView {


    var graphPoints = [Int]()

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let width = rect.width
        let height = rect.height

        let margin:CGFloat = 20.0
        let columnXPoint = { (column:Int) -> CGFloat in
            //Calculate gap between points
            let spacer = (width - margin*2 - 4) /
                CGFloat((self.graphPoints.count - 1))
            var x:CGFloat = CGFloat(column) * spacer
            x += margin + 2
            return x



    }

        let topBorder:CGFloat = 60
        let bottomBorder:CGFloat = 50
        let graphHeight = height - topBorder - bottomBorder
        let maxValue = graphPoints.maxElement()
        let columnYPoint = { (graphPoint:Int) -> CGFloat in
            var y:CGFloat = CGFloat(graphPoint) /
                CGFloat(maxValue!) * graphHeight
            y = graphHeight + topBorder - y // Flip the graph
            return y
        }

        UIColor.whiteColor().setFill()
        UIColor.whiteColor().setStroke()

        //set up the points line
        let graphPath = UIBezierPath()
        //go to start of line
        graphPath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x:columnXPoint(0),
            y:columnYPoint(graphPoints[0])))

        //add points for each item in the graphPoints array
        //at the correct (x, y) for the point
        for i in 1..<graphPoints.count {
            let nextPoint = CGPoint(x:columnXPoint(i),
                y:columnYPoint(graphPoints[i]))
            graphPath.addLineToPoint(nextPoint)
        }

        graphPath.stroke()

        graphPath.lineWidth = 2.0
        graphPath.stroke()

        //Draw the circles on top of graph stroke
        for i in 0..<graphPoints.count {
            var point = CGPoint(x:columnXPoint(i), y:columnYPoint(graphPoints[i]))
            point.x -= 5.0/2
            point.y -= 5.0/2

            let circle = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect:
                CGRect(origin: point,
                    size: CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 5.0)))
            circle.fill()
        }

    /*
    // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
    }
    */

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UIViewController can be redefined with this variable:

```
@IBOutlet var View1: GonGraphUIView!
```

and in `GonGraphUIView`

```
var graphPoints:[Int]?
```

and then in `drawRect`

```
if let graphPoints = graphPoints {
    // draw the graph
} else { do nothing }
```

so UIViewController can say

```
View1.graphPoints = dataMoneyTracker1
View1.setneedsDisplay()
```

Comment: Thank you! That really helped!!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to solve this problem.

The easiest one is to define `var dataMoneyTracker1 = [Int]()` outside of any class, and then you can always access it.
 Or you can make it a class variable and then you can access it:

```
class GonDetailViewController: UIViewController{
    static var dataMoneyTracker1 = [Int]()
}
class GonGraphUIView : UIView{
    var graphPoints = GonDetailViewController.dataMoneyTracker1
}
```